# PDOException SQLSTATE HY000 2002 Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket ' /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, magento, magento2

i installed magento2 banner module and i try to run below command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

After run this command i get below error:

```
 [Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]                                                  
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '  
 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)                                             


[PDOException]                                                               
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through  socket '  
 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I got this error if anyone have idea then let me know how to solve this ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Usually this means your mySQL stopped or crashed. Please make sure your mySQL is up and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved issue myself by uninstall mysql server and upgrade PHP :)

Answer (score 1):

Confirm that MySQL is running. If it is, then modify your connection to be 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Answer (score 0):

Simply run the commands below for `mySql` to make it work again without un-install.

```
chown mysql:mysql -R /var/lib/mysql/*
chmod 755 -R /var/lib/mysql/*
```

After changing permission restart mysql by ***service mysql restart***.